# How do I run my iOS simulator with iOS7 after Xcode upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, ios8

My Mac upgraded my Xcode to 6 and I can no longer run my apps on an iOS7 simulator. How can I get the old simulator back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After ensuring that your iOS deployment target is 7.1 from the main settings of your project click where you can normally select a simulator size and go down to "Get More Simulators".

You can then download and install the iOS 7.1 simulator and then the options to run them will be available in that same menu.